# JavaScript: What dangers are in extending Array.prototype?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, prototype

Google JavaScript Style Guide [advises against extending the `Array.prototype`](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#disallowed-features-modifying-builtin-objects).
However, I used `Array.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.filter || function(...) {...}` as a way to have it (and similar methods) in browsers where they do not exist. MDN actually provides [similar example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

I am aware about `Object.prototype` issues, but `Array` is not a hash table.

What issues may arise while extending `Array.prototype` that made Google advise against it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Most people missed the point on this one. Polyfilling or shimming standard functionality like `Array.prototype.filter` so that it works in older browsers *is* a good idea in my opinion. Don't listen to the haters. Mozilla even shows you how to do this on the MDN. Usually the advice for not extending `Array.prototype` or other native prototypes might come down to one of these:

1. `for..in` might not work properly
2. Someone else might also want to extend Array with the same function name
3. It might not work properly in every browser, even with the shim.

Here are my responses:

1. You don't need to use `for..in` on Array's usually. If you do you can use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure it's legit.
2. Only extend natives when you know you're the only one doing it *OR* when it's standard stuff like `Array.prototype.filter`.
3. This is annoying and has bit me. Old IE sometimes has problems with adding this kind of functionality. You'll just have to see if it works in a case by case basis. For me the problem I had was adding `Object.keys` to IE7. It seemed to stop working under certain circumstances. Your mileage may vary.

Check out these references:

- http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/
- http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Good luck!

Comment: "You don't need to use for..in" -- don't use it at all.  Even with `hasOwnProperty`, you'll still step over `length`, which makes no sense in most cases.

Comment: @Malvolio Disagree: You cannot easily know / control what is in your 3rd party libraries. For instance, `for..in` breaks in the SEA3D loader for Three.js, with my additions to `Array.prototype`. In fact, much of three.js uses `for..in`. Really, BEWARE. These are not pleasant bugs to have to find.

Comment: @mrdoob Could this be worth looking into?

Comment: @NickWiggill, for .. in is not designed for arrays, it is designed for arraylike objects (read associative arrays). You should never use for .. in for arrays.

Comment: If you control all your application's code this is great. If you work on a platform (ahem, SharePoint) you risk breaking platform code with issues that will manifest in strange ways on completely unrelated functionality. And since the actual error will occur (usually introduced via a for..in) in minifed platform code it's really difficult to diagnose.

Comment: you can avoid enumeration problems extending the Array.prototype object with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: This is 2018 now. We have `for..of` now. So i do this: `Array.prototype.RemoveElement = function (el) {
  this.splice(this.indexOf(el), 1);
};`

Answer (score 9):

I'll give you the bullet points, with key sentences, from Nicholas Zakas' excellent article [Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/):

- **Dependability**: "The simple explanation is that an enterprise software product needs a consistent and dependable execution environment to be maintainable."
- **Incompatible implementations**: "Another peril of modifying objects that you don’t own is the possibility of naming collisions and incompatible implementations."
- **What if everyone did it?**: "Simply put: if everyone on your team modified objects that they didn’t own, you’d quickly run into naming collisions, incompatible implementations, and maintenance nightmares."

Basically, don't do it. Even if your project is never going to be used by anyone else, and you're never going to import third party code, don't do it. You'll establish a horrible habit that could be hard to break when you start trying to play nice with others.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extending host objects to make them standards compliant if the team agrees to it. Extending host objects with non-standard properties is a different game, and I would agree "don't do it"

Comment: Any reason you can come up with to modify the host objects can easily be overcome by implementing the feature on your own objects. The documentation for the host environment doesn't include your modifications. This can cause confusion no matter what the "team" agrees upon. What about the new guy who comes in and doesn't know all of your host modifications but you've told him it's okay to change host objects? Things can break in a hurry.

Comment: This reasoning in the fact advises against OOP

Comment: _"The documentation for the host environment doesn't include your modifications."_ - What documentation? We're mostly talking here about supporting unknown web browsers that may or may be standards compliant, and just adding in missing features. If you are extending host objects to make them standards compliant (as Raynos mentioned) then presumably as in the question you'd first test if the function already existed and only add your own version if needed.

Comment: @user539484, no it doesn't. It advises being responsible and not thrashing your standard library. If you want to add to it, feel free, but do so on your own objects (subclasses if you will).

Comment: @nnnnnn That doesn't make it good, or recommended, practice. The reasons stated in the article are why the Google advisement exists.

Comment: @jsumners, what if John or Jane already wrote `VeryUsefulObject` but it still missing `exactlyWhatINeed` method?

Comment: But it _is_ recommended for that purpose. It's not _universally_ recommended, and obviously some people recommend _against_ it, but still...

Comment: @jsumners so your saying that [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) and [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) are not useful or correct in their editing of natives with _well-defined_ behaviour?

Comment: @Raynos from that first link: "In many cases, this means that these shims cause many ES5 methods to silently fail."

Comment: @jsumners so what? That's a bonus, You either get well defined behaviour, or as close as you can to it. It's better then using these methods and they don't work at all. The case here is that you need to extend natives with missing features if you want to code to modern standards. You've got no choice and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Breaking standard methods that already exist is a bonus? Okay.

Comment: @jsumners `VeryUsefulObject.prototype.exactlyWhatINeed = VeryUsefulObject.prototype.exactlyWhatINeed || function(){ … }`. Bam. Nothing's being broken here.

Comment: @jsumners I gotta give to you, though, that Raynos and I had a pretty special case of messing with others' objects in mind. Shimming, if done right, is incredibly useful. Generally though, messing with others' stuff is most likely a bad idea for the exact reasons you gave. On a sidenote: Much of the beauty of JS lies in the fact that you *can* mess with others' stuff in a way that is quite unlikely to ever cause any of the above problems if done right.

Comment: "The simple explanation is that an enterprise software product needs a consistent and dependable execution environment to be maintainable." reads to me like: "leverage good tools that bring your execution environment to a known and documented state".  I think polyfills are an acceptable compromise here, unless you would rather just not use array at all.

Answer (score 5):

As a modern update to Jamund Ferguson's answer:

> Usually the advice for not extending Array.prototype or other native prototypes might come down to one of these:
>
> 1. for..in might not work properly
> 2. Someone else might also want to extend Array with the same function name
> 3. It might not work properly in every browser, even with the shim.

Points 1. and 2. can now be mitigated in [ES6](http://es6-features.org) by using a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) to add your method.

It makes for a slightly more clumsy call structure, but adds a property that isn't iterated over and can't be easily duplicated.

```js
// Any string works but a namespace may make library code easier to debug. 
var myMethod = Symbol('MyNamespace::myMethod');

Array.prototype[ myMethod ] = function(){ /* ... */ };

var arr = [];

// slightly clumsier call syntax
arr[myMethod]();

// Also works for objects
Object.prototype[ myMethod ] = function(){ /* ... */ };
```

Pros:

- For..in works as expected, symbols aren't iterated over.
- No clash of method names as symbols are local to scope and take effort to retrieve.

Cons:

- Only works in [modern environments](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Symbol)
- Slightly clunky syntax

Comment: arr[myMethod]() -- Cantcha wrap that in a simpler call?

Comment: @johnywhy yes, but if you do that (say by adding `Array.prototype.f = Array.prototype[ myMethod ]`) then that method is available to (and might clash with) other library code.

Answer (score 3):

Extending `Array.prototype` in your own application code is safe (unless you use `for .. in` on arrays, in which case you need to pay for that and have fun refactoring them).

Extending native host objects in libraries you intend others to use is not cool. You have no right to *corrupt* the environment of other people in your own library.

Either do this behind an optional method like `lib.extendNatives()` or have `[].filter` as a requirement.

[Extending Natives and Host Objects](http://raynos.org/blog/21/Extending-Natives-and-Host-objects)

Answer (score 3):

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) does this. It's evil. The following snippet demonstrates how doing so can produce unexpected results:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  a = ["not", "only", "four", "elements"];
  for (var i in a)
    document.writeln(a[i]);
</script>
```

The result:

```
not only four elements function each(iterator, context) { var index = 0; . . .
```

and about 5000 characters more.

Comment: they're not evil, the evil part is your code, if you wrap this in .hasOwnProperty only it's own properties show up, no offense

Comment: I think it's not syntactically elegant to use .hasOwnProperty for iterating over an array.

Comment: Why would you use for ... in instead of forEach? No need for has ownproperty or messing with scope variables

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an additional answer that allows extending the `Array` prototype without breaking `for .. in` loops, and *without requiring use of `hasOwnPropery`*:

Don't use this bad approach which causes prototype values to appear in `for .. in`:

```js
Array.prototype.foo = function() { return 'foo'; };
Array.prototype.bar = function() { return 'bar'; };

let a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
console.log(`Foo: ${a.foo()}`);
console.log(`Bar: ${a.bar()}`);
console.log('==== Enumerate: ====');
for (let v in a) console.log(v);
```

Instead use `Object.defineProperty`, with `enumerable: false` - it exists for *pretty much exactly this reason*!

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'foo', {
  value: function() { return 'foo'; },
  enumerable: false
});
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'bar', {
  value: function() { return 'bar'; },
  enumerable: false
});

let a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
console.log(`Foo: ${a.foo()}`);
console.log(`Bar: ${a.bar()}`);
console.log('==== Enumerate: ====');
for (let v in a) console.log(v);
```

Note: Overall, I recommend avoiding enumerating `Array`s using `for .. in`. But this knowledge is still useful for extending prototypes of classes where enumeration is appropriate!

Answer (score 2):

Some people use `for ... in` loops to iterate through arrays. If you add a method to the prototype, the loop will also try to iterate over *that* key. Of course, you *shouldn't* use it for this, but some people do anyway.

Comment: They think what they are *iterating*, but in reality they are *enumerating* :-) Such code is broken already, there is no point to support it anyway.

Comment: It's stupid code, sure, but it's still something to be aware of: if you add something to the prototype and start having weird bugs, it could be because of this.

Comment: My point is what this pitfall assumes one has fallen into the pit already :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question deserves an updated **ES6** answer.

**ES5**

First of all, as many people have already stated. Extending the native prototypes to shim or polyfill new standards or fix bugs is standard practice and not harmful. For example if a browser doesn't support the .filter method `if (!Array.prototype.filter)` you are free to add this functionality on your own. In-fact, the language is designed to do exactly this to manage backwards compatibility.

Now, you'd be forgving for thinking that since JavaScript object use prototypal inheritance, extending a native object like `Array.prototype` without interfering should be easy, but up until ES6 it's not been feasible.

Unlike objects for example, you had to rely and modifying the `Array.prototype` to add your own custom methods. As others have pointed out, **this is bad** because it pollutes the Global namespace, can interfere with other code in an unexpected way, has potential security issues, is a cardinal sin etc.

In ES5 you can try hacking this but the implementations aren't really practically useful. For more in depth information, I recommend you check out this very informative post: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

You can add a method to an array, or even an array constructor but you run into issues trying to work with the native array methods that rely on the length property. Worst of all, these methods are going to return a native `Array.prototype` and not your shiny new sub-class array, ie: `subClassArray.slice(0) instanceof subClassArray === false`.

**ES6**

However, now with ES6 you can subclass builtins using `class` combined with `extends Array` that overcomes all these issues. It leaves the `Array.prototype` intact, creates a new sub-class and the array methods it inherits will be of the same sub-class! https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-subclassing/

See the fiddle below for a demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/dmq8o0q4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create somekind of sandbox with `poser` library.

Take a look on https://github.com/bevacqua/poser

```
var Array2 = require('poser').Array();
// <- Array

Array2.prototype.eat = function () {
  var r = this[0];
  delete this[0];
  console.log('Y U NO .shift()?');
  return r;
};

var a = new Array2(3, 5, 7);

console.log(Object.keys(Array2.prototype), Object.keys(Array.prototype))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the prototype is a trick that only works once.  You do *and* you use a library that also does it (in an incompatible way) and *boom*!

Comment: That's why we only use well written compatible libraries.

Comment: A rule that only works if you define "well-written" as including "does not extend Array.prototype"!

Comment: Of course... That's kind of the definition of well written, well written libraries don't corrupt the environment they don't own.

Comment: That's a good answer to the original question: "don't corrupt the environment you don't own".  You aren't the only one using Array -- don't mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are overriding could be used by the internal javascript calls and that could lead to unexpected results. Thats one of the reasons for the guideline

For example I overrode indexOf function of array and it messed up accessing array using [].

Comment: I doubt it messes up `[]`. Unless you did something horribly wrong

Comment: Yup it did because [] access now returns a indexOf override function instead of data.

Comment: When you define your own `indexOf` surely you first test that the function doesn't already exist? Add your own only when the browser doesn't already support it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an issue of extending a native prototype, but rather an issue of clobbering standard methods with non standard ones.