# Is using Prototype to extend native objects bad?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I read somewhere that using `prototype` to extend native objects (`String`, `Number`, `Array`, etc.) was a bad idea. Is this true? Why or why not?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question of some worth, imo. It shouldn't be closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask says it isn't.

Comment: Basically a dup 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype/8859941#8859941

Comment: See also: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Who closed this question? GTFO! This is completely valid and should be reopened. This is a HUGE issue in code quality. @vascowhite what guideline in there says this shouldn't be a question?

Comment: See also: [Revisiting extending native prototypes after ECMAScript 5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11781878/1048572) and [Modifying built-in prototypes in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36746555/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's bad. If you have a look at Ruby on Rails, very many native objects are extended with custom functionality and it's a very good framework.

What would be bad is if you **change existing methods** on native objects. this could cause unforseen consequences.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, that would make sense.

Comment: The real problem though is that you don't know what methods will exist in the future (e.g. if they are added to the standard). You can keep overwriting them and your own code will continue to work, but you won't be able to upgrade libraries that will try to use the new native methods in the future.

Answer (score 5):

There's a great discussion about this in this video from JSConf 2011 by Andrew Dupont. http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542

Basically the points are:

- Don't extend `Object.prototype`
- Some people might like to extend things, some people don't
- You need to know what you're doing
- Don't use two libraries that extend things, because it can be bad
- Extending prototypes to add standard functionality is almost always ok.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay clear of extending/modifying behavior of native objects.

It at least makes sense when developing in a team environment.

Simply because, months later, another developer writing another independent piece of code isn't immediately going to recognize the changed behavior unless documented somewhere and made aware of it prior to starting his task.

Instead, I suggest encapsulating/"namespace"-ing all such functionality such that somebody may chose to or not to use the modified functions.

Also, native objects and their methods are thoroughly tested for wide-ranging cases. So you you'd have to be completely sure of what you're doing before modifying native functionality.