# Javascript take part from string untill

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
'Hello there everyone I'm Bob, I want to say something.'
```

Imagine me having this string, I'm wondering if there is a function which you can give to strings to search for in a string. The first string I is like the start, the second one should be the end. In example: I give the following strings to the function "Hello" and "I'". Then I want the function to return " there everyone " to me.

jQuery will do as well.

Comment: indexOf will do, but I would do it in regex.

Comment: It's certainly possible to write such a function, but it doesn't exist natively.

Comment: but what if later you want returns `there everyone I'm Bob,` that between  "Hello" and "I"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression.

```
str = "Hello there everyone I'm Bob, I want to say something.";
result = str.match(/Hello(.*?)I/);
alert(result[1]);
```

`*?` for non-greedy match. http://jsfiddle.net/LV5t3/

Comment: Just wondering; what if my string was 'Hello, they're going to Ibiza, I ' not going.' - How can I get the part after "they'" until "' " ? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/LLuz8/):

```
var first = str.indexOf("Hello");
var second = str.indexOf("I'm", first + from.length);
var result = str.substring(first + "Hello".length, second);
```

You can of course extract that into a function:

```
function between(str, from, to){
    var first = str.indexOf(from);
    var second = str.indexOf(to, first + from.length);
    return str.substring(first + from.length, second);
}
between(yourStr,"Hello","I'm");
```

Alternatively, you can extend `String.prototype` [if that's your thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781878/revisiting-extending-native-prototypes-after-ecmascript-5):

```
String.prototype.between = function(from, to){
    var first = this.indexOf(from);
    var second = this.indexOf(to, first + from.length);
    return this.substring(first + from.length, second);
}
// now this will work
str.between("Hello","I'm"); // " there everyone "
```

Comment: It's probably better to do `str.indexOf("I'm", first);`, to only look for the end token after the start token.

Comment: @FelixKling nice catch, for the general case it is probably better - I'll edit it in.

Comment: @FelixKling so i think `str.indexOf("I'm", first+"Hello".length);` is better if we search full word

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Hello there everyone I'm Bob, I want to say something.";
var first = "Hello";
var second = "I";

var start = str.indexOf(first)+first.length;
var end = str.indexOf(second);

var subStr= str.slice(start , end);

console.log(subStr) // there everyone
```

Comment: why you need `str.indexOf(second)-second.length` instead of `str.indexOf(second)`?