# Export/Import custom function of built-in object in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a 'custom' directory where I would like to store any changes to the prototypes of built-in objects. Each built-in object that's modified will have its own file (i.e `custom/String.js` for any modifications to `String.prototype`).

In addition to these files, I will have a file called `custom/All.js` which will be used to export the custom functionality to be used.

**All.js**

```
export * from './String'
export {Multiply} from './Array'
```

**main.js**

```
import * from './custom/All'
```

**String.js**

```
// something like this
export String.prototype.doSomething = function() {}
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: So you want to export it and modify the prototype?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, pretty much. Essentially I would like to import the changes to String's prototype more-so than the function itself (if that's even possible)

Comment: @Rajesh No. That's even weirder to use.

Comment: @Rajesh My preference is to modify `String.prototype` directly as this will be a widespread change across the codebase. Extending from String will require me to have to import this new class in any of the files that use it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course [it's still considered a bad idea to extend builtin prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10197174/1048572), [even in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11781878/1048572), but if you insist on doing it anyway instead of a simple-to-use module of static helper functions:

You should not `export` anything. Those are mutations, and don't have any value. You only need to include the module code for its side effects.

```
// main.js
import './custom';
```

```
// custom/index.js
import './String';
import './Array';
```

```
// custom/String.js
String.prototype.doSomething = function() {};
```