# How do you replicate something like function(){ ... }.property() in javascript like in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ember uses something like:

```
val: function(){ 
    ...
}.property()
```

and things like:

```
func: function(){
}.observes('someValue')
```

I think the fact that you can add a property to the end of a function is quite neat and would like to replicated it.However, I could not find where either of those things are implemented in the source and am wondering if anyone knows?

Also, more importantly, what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one of the [`Function`s methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Function_instances), just like `call` or `bind`.

You can add other methods by extending the native `Function.prototype` object. Whether that is a good practice is [discussable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10197174/1048572), though; also have a look at [these](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/) [articles](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/).

Comment: If you would like to see how Ember implements this, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/function.js. Also note that if you conclude this is a not a good idea, Ember makes this behavior configurable by setting `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` to false.