# scroll an array with looping

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you efficiently scroll an array with looping either acting on the array itself or returning a new array

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

i want to do something like this:

```
arr.scroll(-2)

arr now is [4,5,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
> arr.slice(-2).concat(arr.slice(0, -2));
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype) then generalize it and extend `Array.prototype` with the `scroll` function:

```
Array.prototype.scroll = ​function (shift) {
    return this.slice(shift).concat(this.slice(0, shift));
}​;

> arr.scroll(-2);
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```