# Can I add a function to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had this code suggested to me:

```
var activityArray = [];
activityArray.push("Loading content 1");
activityArray.push("Loading content 2");
activityArray.push("Loading content 3");
activityArray.push("Loading content 4");

//find the item we want to delete
var index = activityArray.indexOf('Loading content 4');// returns 3
activityArray.splice(index,1)//remove the item at index 3
```

I have a lot of places where I want to add elements to my array so "`activityArray.push`" seems like a very easy way to do this.

I also have a lot of places where I want to remove the elements from the array. Is there a way that I could take the code to delete the item and add it as a function to activityArray so that I could say:

```
activityArray.pull("Loading content 4");
```

Comment: Perhaps you're asking "how do I extend the Array type in javascript?" This might give you good contextual information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Javascript's [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) system makes it very easy to [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) new functionality onto existing objects.

This version, like your code, will return the *first instance* of the removed element, or `undefined` if the element did not exist in the array.

```
Array.prototype.pull = function(element) { 
  var index = this.indexOf(element); 
  var removed = undefined;
  if(index >= 0)
    removed = this.splice(index,1); 
  return removed;
}
```

If you just want to add the method to a single array,

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

myArray.pull = function(element) { 
  var index = this.indexOf(element); 
  var removed = undefined;
  if(index >= 0)
    removed = this.splice(index,1); 
  return removed;
}

myArray.pull(3) // -> [1,2,4,5,6]
[3,2,1].pull(2) // -> exception
```

Comment: `var removed = undefined;` is excessive. `var removed;` will be enough.

Comment: That is true, but there is no harm in being explicit - it makes the functionality more obvious to a novice.

Comment: @Alan FYI: prototype meddling is not recommended (especially using the name `pull`) as this might someday be used as an actual prototype method and cause you some serious headaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can add methods to the array prototype for instance specific methods.

```
Array.prototype.pull = function(content) {
    var index = this.indexOf(content);
    this.splice(index, 1);
};

var activityArray = [];
activityArray.push("Loading content 1");
activityArray.push("Loading content 2");
activityArray.push("Loading content 3");
activityArray.push("Loading content 4");

activityArray.pull("Loading content 4"); 

>> ["Loading content 1", "Loading content 2", "Loading content 3"]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can apply it to just the activityArray object ?

Comment: See my updated answer for a version that works on a single array.

Comment: joews - Did you change anything. The answer looks the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you can skip using a simple `Array` try a `named array` \ `object` syntax:

```
var activityArray = {};

activityArray["Loading content 1"] = "Loading content 1";
activityArray["Loading content 2"] = "Loading content 2";
activityArray["Loading content 3"] = "Loading content 3";
activityArray["Loading content 4"] = "Loading content 4";

// To remove simply use the `delete` keyword
delete activityArray["Loading content 4"];
```

Comment: This is a good answer provided that each element can exist only once in the data structure. Given that the other answers, and the OP's code, will only remove the first instance of a given element anyway, that is a pretty good assumption to make.