# Does shimming map / reduce / filter work in Exploder 6 / 7 / 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype, backwards-compatibility, shim

I was writing something and in my research found that arrays are documented to have map/reduce/filter, but not in IE ?8? or older. So I poked around, found [JavaScript: What dangers are in extending Array.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype), and besides several responses to cool my enthusiasm for extending Array.prototype (perhaps even as a shim), the accepted response said:

> ...This is annoying and has bit me. Old IE sometimes has problems with
>   adding this kind of functionality. You'll just have to see if it works
>   in a case by case basis. For me the problem I had was adding
>   Object.keys to IE7. It seemed to stop working under certain
>   circumstances. Your mileage may vary.

So, in other words, my use case was to shim for older IE was a mechanism that may be dodgy in older IE.

So if I want to support old IE, I should make and use my own standalone map / reduce / filter? I'm planning on taking a different approach in what I am writing now, but it would be nice to know for reference's sake, "If I want feature X that is not in browser Y, and shims may break in browser Y, what is the preferred approach?"

Comment: Try it and see. It's probably more common to instead create a collection of methods that use the native method if it's available, else, use a custom built method. underscore.js and jQuery uses that technique.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with extending natives, as long as it's done correctly:

```
if(!Array.prototype.map) {
  Array.prototype.map = //your shim
}
```

This way, you're not clobbering native methods that already exist.

Just make sure your shims stay up to date with the spec/current implementations otherwise you'll run into some very confusing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically are trying to add es5 array functions like map, reduce, filter, etc. then you can use the [es5-shim library](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) which will add shims for a variety of es5 features including those array functions and works in older versions of IE.