# Javascript - Change index of array element

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array with

[1,2,3,4,5]

I want to move "2" right (1 position at the time)
or move "2" left

Can we do that with RxJS Operators?

Comment: so, what is your desired output?

Comment: [1,3,2,4,5] if i move the "2" right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an array element from one array position to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it with regular javascript

```js
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8859828/215552 Not usually a great idea to extend `Array.prototype`.