# Performing the same filter and map function on 2 separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to filter through and then map 2 separate arrays. Normally I would just combine them, but I would like to keep them separate to make some logic later on a little easier.

Basically, I have 2 arrays:

```
const arr1 = [ {obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3} ];
const arr2 = [ {obj4}, {obj5}, {obj6} ];
```

I want to run (2) filters and (1) across these arrays like so:

```
arr1.filter(obj => obj.color !== 'red')
.filter(obj => obj.shape !== 'circle')
.map(obj => {
  //logic
}
```

However, I need to run the exact same filters, without merging my two arrays. So filtering a new variable with `[...arr1, ...arr2]` is out of the questions

I've been trying to do something along the lines of:

```
arr1.concat(arr2).filter....
```

But I don't believe `concat` can process with filter.

Are there another array methods that might help me handle this, I can't seem to get the correct result

Comment: > But I don't believe concat can process with filter.

why not?

Comment: @jakemingolla When running it, I'm getting filter is not a function

Comment: Why not just make the snippet into a function `filterAndMap(array)`, and call it on both? Something like `var arr1Filtered = filterAndMap(arr1); var arr2Filtered = filterAndMap(arr2);`

Comment: Can you please give the input and expected output

Comment: Most likely `arr1` is actually a string, and you're mistakenly calling the [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) method of a string -- which returns a new string and not an array. Also if `arr1` and `arr2` are arrays, `[...arr1, ...arr2]` is equivalent to `arr1.concat(arr2)`.

Comment: I'm not sure the `concat` portion really matters, given that it merges two or more arrays, and you've specifically noted that you do *not* want to do this. Granted, the fact that `concat` isn't allowing you to `filter` may point to a misrepresented type.

Comment: I'm not clear why spreading them into a new var won't work. Could you explain that? Also, why not combine the 2 filters like `.filter(obj => obj.color !== 'red' && obj.shape !== 'circle')` so you don't have to loop twice before the map?

Comment: @Scrimothy OP said he specifically wanted to leave them separated. If you were going to combine methods, I'd argue that one `.reduce()` could do the job of a `.filter()` and a `.map()` with less iterations.

Comment: Please provide a snippet that demonstrates that `concat(...).filter` gives an error.

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm thinking making it a small helper function is my best bet given the situation

Comment: @TylerRoper, right, but if he's trying to use `concat`, isn't that just combining them? My confusion is why spread doesn't work but concat is acceptable.

Comment: @Scrimothy I was under the impression that concat wasn't combining, but allowed me to run the filter series twice. That is my mistake

Comment: Note: If you don't assign the result of the filter back to `arr1`, then `arr1` will not be filtered anyway. Is your purpose to actually eliminate elements from `arr1` and `arr2` through the filter, or do you just want to process/mutate some of the objects they contain?

Comment: @knockedloose ah ok, got it. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: This whole thread of comments would not have been necessary if you would have provided a few of concrete examples of input and output. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably just create a separate function to do this, like so...

```js
const arr1 = [ {color: "blue", shape: "triangle"}, {color: "red", shape: "square"}, {color: "green", shape: "circle"} ];
const arr2 = [ {color: "purple", shape: "diamond"}, {color: "yellow", shape: "square"}, {color: "orange", shape: "circle"} ];

const applyFiltersAndMap = (array) => {
  return array.filter(obj => obj.color !== 'red')
              .filter(obj => obj.shape !== 'circle')
              .map(obj => `${obj.color} ${obj.shape}`);
};

console.log(applyFiltersAndMap(arr1));
console.log(applyFiltersAndMap(arr2));
```

That said, I know you specified that you wanted to keep the methods separate for more complex logic, however I'd still suggest using `reduce()` to limit iterations.

You could alter your method to take a list of filter expressions and a map, applying them within a `reduce()`. This would keep your separated/clean filter functionality, while still using a more efficient array method in `reduce`.

```js
const arr1 = [ {color: "blue", shape: "triangle"}, {color: "red", shape: "square"}, {color: "green", shape: "circle"} ];
const arr2 = [ {color: "purple", shape: "diamond"}, {color: "yellow", shape: "square"}, {color: "orange", shape: "circle"} ];

const applyFiltersAndMap = (array, filters, mapper) => {
  return array.reduce((out,e) => {
    if (filters.every(f => f(e))) out.push(mapper(e)); //filter and map
    return out;
  }, []);
};

const filters = [                                  //your filter functions
  obj => obj.color !== 'red',
  obj => obj.shape !== 'circle'
];
const mapper = obj => `${obj.color} ${obj.shape}`; //your map function

console.log(applyFiltersAndMap(arr1, filters, mapper));
console.log(applyFiltersAndMap(arr2, filters, mapper));
```

Or if you don't mind [extending `Array.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype)...

```js
const arr1 = [ {color: "blue", shape: "triangle"}, {color: "red", shape: "square"}, {color: "green", shape: "circle"} ];
const arr2 = [ {color: "purple", shape: "diamond"}, {color: "yellow", shape: "square"}, {color: "orange", shape: "circle"} ];

Array.prototype.applyFiltersAndMap = function(filters, mapper) {
  return this.reduce((out,e) => {
    if (filters.every(f => f(e))) out.push(mapper(e)); //filter and map
    return out;
  }, []);
};

const filters = [                                  //your filter functions
  obj => obj.color !== 'red',
  obj => obj.shape !== 'circle'
];
const mapper = obj => `${obj.color} ${obj.shape}`; //your map function

console.log(arr1.applyFiltersAndMap(filters, mapper));
console.log(arr2.applyFiltersAndMap(filters, mapper));
```

Comment: Thanks for the super thorough response, this is the route I ended up taking, as I was misusing `concat`. Thanks again!

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks for catching the call to `mapper()` that I missed in my suggestion. Good answer.