# Create new prototype to search any array and return string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to go through an array of words stored in a variable. I created a Array.prototype.findWord so I can search for any word in any array in my program.

I had my findWord(str, arr) take a string and array as params. Then I looped through the array passed. If the string passed matches the string in the array, it will log the string.

```
Array.prototype.findWord = function(str, arr) {
  //   let returnWord = "";
  str = "";
  arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === str) {
      return str;
    }
  }
```

This passes undefined.

Comment: How are you calling this method? Can you provide a complete example, please?

Comment: Why make it a prototype method when you want to pass `arr` as a parameter?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you don't want to overwrite your arguments with empty values.

Comment: I have an array of words. I want to use this to pass a word and console the result;

Comment: please add some data as array and the wanted result with a search string.

Comment: var commonWords = [
    "the",
    "of",
    "and",
    "a",
    "to"]
commonWords.findWord("and", commonWords) 
and it should console log the result

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype

If you decide to extend the prototype anyhow, you would call it as `myArray.findWords('word')`

The array itself is now the `this` of the function. Hope that helps

Comment: Why not just use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the first match in the array.  Since you are creating a prototype method you don't need to pass an array as an argument. Prototype methods are called on an instance of a class which in this case is an array.  So you will call the method like this:

```
['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'].findWord('ipsum');
```

The prototype method will need rewritten referencing `this` rather than a passing `arr`.

```
Array.prototype.findWord = function(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    // if they match
    if (this[i] === str) {
      return str;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [JavaScript: What dangers are in extending Array.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype) before you decide to extend array prototype

If you decide to extend it anyhow, you would call it as `myArray.findWords('word')`

The array itself is now the `this` of the function. Hope that helps

```
Array.prototype.findWord = function(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] === str) {
      return str
    }
  }
}

let myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three']
myArray.find('one')
myArray.find('x')
```