# How to transform and reorder array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

Is there an elegant way to reorder JavaScript array? For example, says I have an array like  this:

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now I want to rearrange this to

```js
['b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

Is there a built-in higher-order function to do that in JavaScript? Something like

```js
let reordered = array.reorderMagic([1, 0, 0, 2, 0])
```

Where I could just specify an index array? If not, can you suggest a library that can help me do these kinds of matrix-like manipulations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a method on `Array.prototype` though It is not recommended

> **[Read: JavaScript: What dangers are in extending Array.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype)**

```js
if (!('reorderMagic' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.reorderMagic = function(ref) {
    const arr = this;
    return ref.map((n) => arr[n]);
  };
}

let array = ["a", "b", "c"];
let reordered = array.reorderMagic([1, 0, 0, 2, 0]);
console.log(reordered);
```

**`But I won't recommend that because there might be a scenario where someone or any library might override your method(This is just one scenario)`**

So you can just make a utility function and get the desired result as:

```js
function reorderMagic(arr, ref) {
  return ref.map((n) => arr[n]);
}

let array = ["a", "b", "c"];
let reordered = reorderMagic(array, [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]);
console.log(reordered);
```

Comment: If you're adding a new method to a prototype it's always been good practice (even if the name of the method is obscure) to check that it doesn't already exist. `if (!('reorderMagic' in Array.prototype)) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a method on Array.prototype

Extending `Array.prototype` is considered bad practice, but the rest of the solution does work well.

I would recommend an API something like this instead:

```js
function chooseIndices(arr, indexes) {
  return indexes.map(i => arr[i]);
}
```

And then use it as such:

```js
let array = ["a", "b", "c"];
let reordered = chooseIndices(array, [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]);
// reordered === ['b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

### Caution:

The function above doesn't account for invalid indices. For example, if you use the index `5` in the example above, you'll just get an `undefined` for it.

You can decide how you want to handle invalid indices. But one option would be to simply `filter` those out before using the index array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const order = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0];

const reorderMagic = (arr, indexes) => indexes.map((i) => arr[i]);

console.log(reorderMagic(arr, order));
// [ "b","a","a","c","a"]
```